# Mixing Boost versions in linked libraries

Tags: c++, boost, mongodb-c

I'm have an application, which uses Boost and uses the MongoDB Cxx driver 2.2 (which has to use Boost 1.48 because of Boost Filesystem v2) in a statically linked library.

Now I want to upgrade the Boost version for the application to 1.54 to use Boost.Log.

Is it possible to do that and should there be any subtle bugs expected, when using 1.54 and linking to a lib, which uses 1.48?

Note: I cannot upgrade the MongoDB Cxx driver as the application has to run on Windows XP.

Comment: You link to older Boost version statically (via 3rd party static lib), and now you want to statically link another Boost version? This won't even link due to multiple definitions of the same symbols. If you were using MongoDB as a shared lib (don't know if it's possible), then you could try and link your application statically with a newer Boost, assuming that you would't pass Boost types across 3rd party lib boundaries.

Comment: That's what I assumed. Thanks for your input